# How to regenerate/create adbkey and adbkey.pub from the command line?

Tags: android-sdk

I'm starting to mess with Android SDK (on Ubuntu GNU/Linux), and am seeing stuff like running the `tools/android` and its GUI, `adb` or `gradlew` for the first time. So, I'm trying to set this up, and in reading stuff around, I see mention of `~/.android/adbkey` and `~/.android/adbkey.pub`. As far as I understand, these are the automatically generated debug keys - but I cannot tell: are these the same on every computer where the SDK gets installed, or are they different?

So I look into `~/.android`, and they are indeed there; and I guess in a moment of madness, I decided to delete them (I guess to see what happens `:)`). Anyways, I soon regretted it, and I tried to look up online how to regenerate them. Unfortunately, I cannot find any explicit reference saying what command I should run, in order to get these file generated/recreated.

So that is my question - what tools should I run, to re-generate these keys?

---

EDIT: I tried re-running `sdk/tools/android`, it doesn't reconstruct the keys. Then I tried deleting the `~/.android` folder:

```
rm -rf ~/.android
sdk/tools/android
```

... and after re-running `sdk/tools/android`, the `~/.android` folder *does* get reconstructed, but *not* the `adbkey*` files.

---

Answer from comments (better formatted):

Ah, found it (via [linux - Android Debug Bridge (adb) device - no permissions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460656/android-debug-bridge-adb-device-no-permissions/21027562#21027562)); what I did was:

```
$ sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached 

$ sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
$ ls ~/.android/
adbkey  adbkey.pub  androidwin.cfg  avd  cache  repositories.cfg  sites-settings.cf
```

Comment: Ah, found it (via [linux - Android Debug Bridge (adb) device - no permissions - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460656/android-debug-bridge-adb-device-no-permissions/21027562#21027562)); what I did was:

    $ sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    $ sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
    List of devices attached 
    
    $ sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
    $ ls ~/.android/
    adbkey  adbkey.pub  androidwin.cfg  avd  cache  repositories.cfg  sites-settings.cf

Comment: ... Basically, one just has to rerun the `adb` server, possibly ask for `devices` list, and close the server; after that the `adbkey` file are rebuilt.
(shame one cannot answer own question before 8hrs expire; this comment would have looked better as an answer)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224078